# ModelChoiceField gives “Select a valid choice” populating select with ajax call

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-forms

I've tried all possible solutions on several threads and I'm still unable to fix the problem. I have the following code:

**models.py**

```
class CustomerVisit(models.Model):
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
  address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

**forms.py**

```
address = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Address',
                                 queryset=Address.objects.none(),
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width: 100%;'}))
customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Customer',
                                  queryset=Customer.objects.all(),
                          widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width: 100%;'}))
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    # Cleaning fields
    post = request.POST.copy()
    post['address'] = Address.objects.get(id=post['address'])
    post['start_date'] = dateparser.parse(post['start_date'])
    post['end_date'] = dateparser.parse(post['end_date'])
    # Updating request.POST
    request.POST = post
    form = CustomerVisitForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect("customervisit:calendar")
```

**js**

```
$("#id_customer").select2({}).on("change", function () {
    var customer_id = $("#id_customer").val();
    var id_address = $("#id_address");
    id_address.select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '/get_customer_address/' + customer_id,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: function (params) {

                var queryParameters = {
                    term: params.term
                }
                return queryParameters;
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.text,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My `address` select its being populated based on `customer` selection using [ajax call using select2](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax). After reading several threads I noticed that `modelchoicefield` expects a `Address` object so that's why I'm using the following code on my view before the form is being validated: `post['address'] = Address.objects.get(id=post['address'])` but I'm still getting the `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` error

I'm using `queryset=Address.objects.none(),` because I need an empty select

Comment: You shouldn't do this. All that logic should go in the form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I believe you are talking about the cleaning fields right? If so, I have a TODO to change this. thanks

Comment: But the point is you don't want to do that conversion for the address field. I don't know why you think it needs an instance, the whole point of form fields is that they take POST data and convert it into the appropriate types.

Comment: I'm doing because django is always showing the same error, `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` from that select that's being generated using ajax call

Comment: But that is because you are using `.none()` as the field's queryset.

Comment: Mmm but if I use all() my select gets populated by all the values, what do you suggest?

Comment: @DanielRoseman found the issue, please see my answer, not sure how to give you credits for your time, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

If someone in the future have the same error as me, checking `to_python` method from the `ModelChoiceField` saved my day:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value in self.empty_values:
        return None
    try:
        key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
        value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})
    except (ValueError, TypeError, self.queryset.model.DoesNotExist):
        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_choice'], code='invalid_choice')
    return value
```

So I changed my `queryset` to `queryset=Address.objects` instead of `queryset=Address.objects.none()` or `queryset=Address.objects.all()`

Thanks Daniel Roseman for your comments

Answer (score 2):

I know what you're trying to achieve, my solution would be to initialise the field as charfield with widget select, and then override the clean method. Example:

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    customer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'min-width: 150px;'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        exclude = ['id', 'created', 'is_paid']

    def clean_customer(self):
        customer_id = self.cleaned_data['customer']
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
        if customer: 
            return customer 
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Customer ID invalid")
```